# How can I incorporate sound into Lottie animations in React Native using .json files?

Tags: react-native, animation, audio, lottie-react-native

I'm working on a React Native project and using Lottie animations with .json files to add some visual flair to my app. However, I'd like to enhance the user experience by including sound effects that sync up with specific animations. Is there a way to achieve this in Lottie for React Native? What libraries or methods can I use to seamlessly integrate sound into my Lottie animations, ensuring they are in perfect harmony with the visuals?

i am using lottie-react-native package.